# Power Automate add item to Microsoft To Do "Assigned to me"

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, microsoft-todo

I am trying to connect to azure devops and when a work item is updated, I am adding the work items details to Microsoft Todo(to-do.office.com). I am able to push messages as Tasks or Flagged email but I do not have option to move todo item to "Assigned to me". While configuring todo step in power automate, I only see "Flagged email" and "Tasks" options available in "To-do-List". I tried to manually enter "Assigned to me" but it textbox did not accepted it. Is there any option to move a item from azure dev ops to Microsoft todo "assigned to me" using power automate?

Comment: It looks like it is a limitation of the connector and also the Graph API. When I use the list Lists method of the Graph API that Assigned to Me list is also absent. Like you say, the Flagged Email and Tasks are shown. Maybe contact Microsoft support and flag this as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planner and To Do are integrated. Probably the easiest workaround would be to use a Planner plan as a temporary storage of tasks and assign them in that type of action. After that planner task has been created it should also show up as an assigned item in To Do.

1. The flow setup. In this example I used a Task work item type

[image]

2. The item should show up in the Assigned to me overview

[image]